# Calculate collective duration of remaining todo list items?

Tags: org-mode, time-date, todo

I want Emacs to automatically calculate the duration of my remaining todo list items.

E.g. I have:

```
- [X] Item #0
- [ ] Item #1
- [ ] Item #2
```

And I need to define item duration somehow, not sure of the best way but:

```
- [X] Item #0|01:00
- [ ] Item #1|00:30
- [ ] Item #2|00:45
```

And then display the remaining duration somehow:

```
- [X] Item #0|01:00
- [ ] Item #1|00:30
- [ ] Item #2|00:45
Duration: 01:15
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are these headlines or list items? The asterisk suggests headlines but headlines don't take check boxes. To be sure, asterisks can also be used as list bullets, but if you really mean items in a list, make them `-`. That should clarify things.

Comment: @NickD My headlines can take check boxes just fine, could it be because I'm using [Doom Emacs](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs)?

Comment: Can you check off check boxes on headlines with `org-toggle-checkbox`? If not, that's just some text that you added manually - and something that you can add anywhere you want - but that does not mean that Org mode parses it as a checkbox. The main question here is: are these headlines or list items?

Comment: @NickD `org-toggle-checkbox` does not work, you are correct, so I've changed it to `-`, a list.